# Change Php page Dynamically when Specific string get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building a website in PHP language.
I have created three pages: page1, page2 and page3.

I have a text file which contains three strings:

The first string starts with # and ends with %

```
#cuurent~pass~defect,etc%
```

The second string starts with @ and ends with $

```
@message$
```

The third string starts with &

```
&somthing
```

I want to fetch the value of string from text file in my PHP script and when I get the first string, display page1, when I get the second string, display page2, etc.

Please advise.

Comment: i dont see a point in doing this ?

Comment: I think that you better explain what you are trying to achieve instead  of asking for help with the way you decided to implement it, which seems inefficient (see XY questions).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you haven't shown what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a bit strange but you can test for the first and last characters of a string with square bracket notation:

```
<?php

    $my_string = //string from text file

    if($my_string[0] == "#" && $my_string[strlen($my_string)-1] == "%") {
        // go to page 1
        header("Location: page1.html");
    } elseif ($my_string[0] == "@" && $my_string[strlen($my_string)-1] == "$") {
        // go to page 2
        header("Location: page2.html");
    } elseif ($my_string[0] == "$") {
        // go to page 3
        header("Location: page3.html");
    } else {
        // handle what to do if the string doesn't meet any of the criteria
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, considering `$string` the string that you are passing:

```
$string = 'abcdef';
if(substr($string,0,1) == '# ')
    header("Location: page1.php");
else if(substr($string,0,1) == '@ ')
    header("Location: page2.php");
else if(substr($string,0,1) == '& ')
    header("Location: page3.php");
```